# Sequencing grouping using Mongo

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to group by field but only for identical following values in an array and count them. As a $group + $count can do but I have to keep sequence. Fast solution is a lot preferred/Aggregation framework is prefered because i have at least 200k document of 14,5MB. The length of the data array is ~8000 for 1 document.

I didn't find any way to do it despite many hours of google. I don't really want to map/reduce here (even if it could be interesting to see how to do it this way)

```
{
    header : {
        Number : 1,
        type : 1
    }

    Data : [
        datafield: {
            Status: A,
            ramdomfield : random
        },

        datafield: {
            Status: A,
            ramdomfield : random
        },

        datafield: {
            Status: B,
            ramdomfield : random
        },

        datafield: {
            Status: C,
            ramdomfield : random
        },

        datafield: {
            Status: A,
            ramdomfield : random
        },

        datafield: {
            Status: A,
            ramdomfield : random
        },

    ]
}
```

Expected result :

```
{
    header : {
        Number : 1,
        type : 1
    },

    data: {
        Status A : 2,
        Status B : 1,
        Status C : 1,
        Status A : 2 
    }
}
```

expected result may be more flexible, I just need the count information and keep the sequence order

Thank you !

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted

Comment: Ty for your feedback, it is ok now? Sorry it's my first post and didn't expect it took that much time.